# CRLF in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript. I am trying to write a function that will recognize if the CRLF in the printed Line. Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example of how you would like it to work? (CRLF is defined in the constant `vbCrLf`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `result = Instr(yourString, vbCRLF)`.

It will return an index greater than 0 if the CRLF character sequence exists in `yourString`, and 0 otherwise.